# Запись в кастомную таблицу с front end (данные из формы)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, form

Как при клике на submit отправлять данные в таблицу mysql в соотвествующие столбцы?

форма:

```
 <form action="/ekz.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="jjkk1">
 <input type="text" name="jjkk2">
 <input type="text" name="jjkk3">
 <input type="text" name="jjkk4">
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

база данных:

[image]
<sub>(источник: [userapi.com](https://sun1.informsvyaz.userapi.com/j1CKPHgH9Qvssc9RMwl9omEDIiNlwF3DXyjPeg/A1oC71df9JU.jpg))</sub>

Пробую делать вот так (не работает, ошибок не выдает):

Что-то я никак не могу заставить работать:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 global $wpdb;

 $a=$_POST['jjkk1'];
 $b=$_POST['jjkk2'];
 $c=$_POST['jjkk3'];
 $d=$_POST['jjkk4'];

$wpdb->insert( 'wp_ekz2020', array( 'num1' => $a, 'num2' => $b,'num3' => $c, 
 'num4' => $d), array( '%s', '%s','%s', '%s'  ) );
}

?>
```

Comment: В ВП нет таких таблиц. И тогда поможет https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/

Comment: @SeVlad дополнил вопрос. может подскажете где ошибаюсь

Comment: @Mimzik вы отправляете форму на какой-то файл, в котором нет ядра вп) откуда там wpdb?)

Comment: Где находится обработчик формы? Может ВП не подключён? А что приходит в $_POST - проверял?.. Ну это так на вскидку.  Ну вот ещё глянь пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/18096635

Answer (score 0):

Нужно изменить код формы

```
<form action="" method="post">

 <input type="hidden" name="custom_form_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('custom-form-nonce'); ?>"/>

 <input type="text" name="jjkk1">
 <input type="text" name="jjkk2">
 <input type="text" name="jjkk3">
 <input type="text" name="jjkk4">
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

Вставить в functions.php обработчик

```
add_action('init', 'saveCustomForm');
 
function saveCustomForm() {
    
    global $wpdb;
    
    if(isset($_POST['custom_form_nonce'])  && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_form_nonce'], 'custom-form-nonce')) {
        
        
         $a=$_POST['jjkk1'];
         $b=$_POST['jjkk2'];
         $c=$_POST['jjkk3'];
         $d=$_POST['jjkk4'];
         
         $wpdb->insert( 
                        $wpdb->prefix . 'ekz2020',
                        array( 'num1' => $a, 'num2' => $b,'num3' => $c, 'num4' => $d), 
                        array( '%s', '%s','%s', '%s'  ) 
         );
    }
 }
```

Comment: могу ли я поменять строчку $wpdb->prefix . 'ekz2020' на $wpdb->wp-ekz2020? У меня мультисайт и префикс в данном случае не работает (вроде как)

Comment: $wpdb->prefix на мультисайте тоже работает. имеет значение текущего сайта. также есть $wpdb->base_prefix для root-сайта.